# java.io.NotSerializableException thrown even when serializable is implemented

Tags: java, android, serializable

I'm trying to save a map into a file but I'm getting `java.io.NotSerializableException`. I know this means that I have to implement Serializable to the class. The problem is that It's throwing the error even with Serializable implemented.

Code for storing:

```
private void storePoints(Map<String,WifiPoint> list) throws IOException{
    // store in file
    FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("points", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    os.writeObject(list);
    os.close();
}
```

Wifipoint:

```
public class WifiPoint implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2;
    public String ssid;
    public String bssid;
    public String capabilities;
    public double latitude;
    public double longitude;
    public int level;
}
```

UPDATE:
The real fix was:
I needed to declare the WifiPoint in a separate file insted of declaring it inside another class.

Sorry, I didn't put the codes properly for anybody to get the correct answer

Comment: Please send stack trace. And check what is the concrete implementation of your `Map`. Probably it is not serializable.

Comment: Wait, I think needed a constructor?

Comment: no, you don't need a constructor. Look at cowls' answer (also AlexR)

Comment: Yes, it's most likely a problem with the Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to declare the WifiPoint in a separate file insted of declaring it inside another class.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to serialize the `Map` check that the Map class you are using is `Serializable`

Note: A `HashMap` is `Serializable`, so switch to that if possible.

Comment: this fixed it. I didn't know that HashMap was an implementation of a Map and Map itself is not Serializable

Answer (score 1):

- check that you actually implement `java.io.Serializable`
- check that
  map you want to serialize also implements `java.io.Serializable`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing Map object to storePoints method check whether the Map object you are passing implements Serializable. ( If you are using HashMap, TreeMap of java.util package will definitely implement Serializable. )

Answer (score 0):

Check that Map doesn't implement the Serialization interface :

```
All Known Implementing Classes:
AbstractMap, Attributes, AuthProvider, ConcurrentHashMap, ConcurrentSkipListMap,
EnumMap, HashMap, Hashtable, IdentityHashMap, LinkedHashMap, PrinterStateReasons,             Properties, Provider, RenderingHints, SimpleBindings, TabularDataSupport, TreeMap,
UIDefaults, WeakHashMap
```

Source : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

you can try this : [Java: Writting/Reading a Map from disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738162/java-writting-reading-a-map-from-disk)