# How to read a hashmap from a string

Tags: java, io, hashmap

Say I have this rather complex HashMap:

```
Map<> map = new HashMap<String, HashMap<ArrayList<String>,Double>>();
```

With the `Arrays.asList()` function, it prints out as a string in a readable manner, and I can write it to a text file.

Is there a way to begin with a text file with the output of this HashMap as a string printed into it, and compile it back into a HashMap?

Comment: Have a look at *serialization* and *deserialization*

Comment: Maybe as a first hint: [Java: Writting/Reading a Map from disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738162/java-writting-reading-a-map-from-disk)

Comment: By the way that HashMap declaration strongly suggest that your design is lacking. You have a "map of strings to map of list of strings to double", whereas you really should create some classes where you store that data, ending with something like `Map<String, MyClass>`.